# Chrome API HID receive not working in Windows

Tags: google-chrome, usb, google-chrome-app, hid, hidapi

I have a chromapp which sends data to PC using usb, connected as an HID device, working perfectly in Linux. While trying to do the same in windows, the app sees that the device is connected but throws an runtime error :

```
Unchecked runtime.lastError while running hid.receive: Transfer failed.
```

The hid.receive callback function is implemented as follows

```
var pollDevice = function() {
    var size = 64;
    chrome.hid.receive(connectionId, function(reportId, data) {
      if (data != null) {
        var dataAscii = arrayBufferToString(data);
        console.log(dataAscii);
      }
        setTimeout(pollDevice, 1);
    });
  };
```

I am running Google Chrome Version : 52.0.2743.116 on Windows 10 Pro, Version 1607, Build 14388.0

Did someone else similar issues? Can someone help me out on this??

Comment: See [Smartcard Reader and ChromeApp](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32902729). Maybe the USB driver is at fault, and should be changed.

Comment: I don't see any error with your code. Additional to @wOxxOm's suggestion, it is also stated in this related [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27283505/chrome-hid-send-fails-on-second-use) that the issue is that Windows requires buffers to be the full report size expected by the device. Also, this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34777715/how-to-send-data-to-usb-hid-via-chome-app-javascript) suggested to try new `Uint8Array(64)` and add some error handling inside the callback function:`if (chrome.runtime.lastError) { console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError); }`